# open c# user control from another user control

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a c# user control.
I have a button in this control, and I want that when the user clicks on the button, another user control will be opened.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What sgar91 really means is, what have you tried and where are you stuck? Could you show us some *relevant* and *concise* bits of code that provide an example of your issue?

Comment: If the action is Form-specific, expose an event handler from the UserControl. If it is specific to the UserControl no matter what the host Form does, add that control to your UserControl in the designer, set it to invisible and show it only when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the control you want to add and add it.

```
YourCustomControl uc = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     uc = new YourCustomControl();
     this.Controls.Add(uc); // this represent the user control in which you want to add
                            // You can add it in some container like Panel or GroupBox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `RaiseBubbleEvent`.  This pushes an event up to its parent.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719644(v=vs.71).aspx